# Stuck in paypal terminology

Tags: paypal

I am trying to understand basic paypal terminology.

1) What is PayFlow gateway? Is it the only way to integrate my app with PayPal? Do I use it even for hosted pages?

2) What is PayPal express checkout? The payment process that uses paypal accounts only? I need it to accept paypal payments? Is it based on hosted pages?

3) What is PayFlow Link / Pro? Are these product the only way to work with PayFlow gateway?

I read documentation but things are still not clear for me: probably there is a good system overview?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Payflow gateway is basically Payflow Pro.
2. PayPal Express Checkout is the API-based offering which redirects users back and forth between your website and PayPal. By default only PayPal account holders can use it, but you can specify SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in your initial API call to accept payments from non-PayPal account holders as well. A simpler, HTML-based, alternative to Express Checkout is Website Payments Standard.
3. Payflow Link is the HTML-based version of Payflow. Think of it as the little brother of Payflow Pro, where Website Payments Standard is the little brother for Website Payments Pro.

Express Checkout is available pretty much everywhere, and does not come with a monthly fee.
Website Payments Pro is only available in the US/UK/CA.
Payflow Link and Pro come are only available in the US, AU and (I believe) NZ and Payflow Pro will require you to BYOB (Bring Your Own Bank), basically meanining you'll need to set up a merchant account at a local bank. This only applies to Payflow Pro.

Comment: Thanks! But: 1) why do they have separate documentation for Payflow Gateway and Payflow Pro on x.com? 2) There are 2 types of solutions: API-based (for programmers) and HTML-based (for web-masters), am I right? 3) Payflow pro, Express checkout, Website payments pro are API based. Payflow link and website payments standart are HTML based? 4) I want to use API-based. What is the difference between payflow pro, express checkout and website payments? When use what? 5) Which one I need to accept reccuring payments and could I do it for credit-cards (not paypal accounts only)? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I found info on x.com in devtools / facilitate payments section. Thanks to Robert I am now able to understand it!